# How to manipulate a system of equations

Tags: manipulate, code-review, code-request

I have the following `Manipulate[]` working just fine.

```
Manipulate[
permut = Permutations[{eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5}, {3}];
eq1 = x^a - 4 y - z^b == 1;
eq2 = Sqrt[x] + y + 3 z == 4;
eq3 = x - y^2 + Sqrt[z] == 2;
eq4 = x^a - 4 y^a - z^c == 6;
eq5 = x^b + 6 y - z^c == 8;
NSolve[permut[[eqSet]], {x, y, z}, Reals],
{a, -2, 2, 1},
{b, -2, 2, 1},
{c, -1, 1, 0.5},
{eqSet, 1, Length[permut], 1}
]
```

I want to solve a system of 3 equations with varying parameters. With `Permutations[]` I like to run a different set of 3 equations for each element of index "eqSet". I can do that for each element of `Permutations[]`, no problem. My problem here is that I cannot see the group of 3 equations solved. `eqSet` is an index to pick a set of 3 equations from permutations but I cannot know which set of equations have been solved.

[1] Can I get the names (such as eq1, e2, etc) of the actual set of equations being solved, for example, "eq2, eq5, eq4}"?

[2] Suppose that I solved the set of equations: "{eq2, eq5, eq4}", but now I like to replace "eq2" with equation "eq1" in this set without changing counter value "eqSet". How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: If I replace `NSolve[permut[[eqSet]],{x,y,z},Reals]` with `names=Permutations[{"eq1","eq2","eq3","eq4","eq5"},{3}];
{names[[eqSet]],NSolve[permut[[eqSet]],{x,y,z},Reals]}` then it displays the names of the three equations along with the solution.

Comment: @Bill: Yes, it works in the way I expected. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `RadioButtonBar` to pick the 10 combinations of equations. Use `Subsets[equations, {3}]` instead of `Permutations` because this avoids all the choices where you have a repeated equation.

It's a bit clunky and I didn't know how to represent this very well with the UI elements, but I've also added a `CheckboxBar` so you can select the equations from the first set to replace with equations in the second set.

```
mysolve[a1_, b1_, c1_, d1_, eqs_] := {x, y, z} /. 
  Quiet[NSolve[eqs /. {a -> a1, b -> b1, c -> c1, d -> d1}, {x, y, z},
     Reals]]
permut = Subsets[Range[5], {3}];
equations1 = {x^a - 4 y - z^b == 1, Sqrt[x] + y + 3 z == 4, 
   x - y^2 + Sqrt[z] == 2, x^a - 4 y^a - z^c == 6, 
   x^b + 6 y - z^c == 8};
equations2 = {x^d + Sqrt[6 y] - Sqrt[z^c] == 10, x^b + z^d == 14, 
   x^c + 6 y == 12, x^a + y^d - z^c == 7, 
   x^c + 6 Sqrt[y] - Log[z^d] == 9};
pchoice = First@permut;
Labeled[RadioButtonBar[Dynamic[pchoice], 
  permut], "Choose equations.", Left]
replacementchoices = 
  DeleteCases[
   Flatten[Outer[Rule, Range[Length[equations1]], 
     Range[Length[equations2]]]], x_ -> x_];
Labeled[CheckboxBar[Dynamic[replchoice], 
  ToString /@ replacementchoices], "Choose replacements.", Left]
Manipulate[
 results1 = mysolve[a, b, c, d, equations1[[pchoice]]];
 results2 = If[ListQ[replchoice] && Length[replchoice] > 0,
   newequations = ReplacePart[equations1[[pchoice]],
     With[{choices = ToExpression[replchoice]},
      Thread[choices[[All, 1]] -> equations2[[choices[[All, 2]]]]]]];
   mysolve[a, b, c, d, newequations], {}];
 Column[{equations1[[pchoice]],Labeled[results1, "First result", Left], 
   If[ValueQ[newequations], newequations, Nothing], Labeled[results2, "After replacement", Left]}]
 , {a, -2, 2, 1}, {b, -2, 2, 1}, {c, -1, 1, 0.5}, {d, -1, 1, 0.5}]
```

Comment: I think my second question escaped from your attention. It was a question for "replacing an equation in the system selected  with another equation from the total set of equations".

Comment: But you've already got that from the subsets. Every possible triplet of equations is already present to choose from.

Comment: You are absolutely right that I get it from the subset. My real case is a bit different from the example I gave above. In my real case, I have two sets of equations and after getting a solution to one subset in the first set of equations, I replace one or two equations with an equation from the second set by keeping the parameters fixed. For example, if I get a solution to {eq2,eq4,eq1}, then I go to second set and pick eq5 to replace eq1. Sorry I did not make this point clear in my example just to keep the presentation simple enough.

Comment: Can you provide the second set in your question?

Comment: Here they are: eq6 = x^d + Sqrt[6 y] - Sqrt[z^c] == 10;
eq7 = x^b +  z^d == 14;
eq8 = x^c + 6 y == 12;
eq9 = x^a + y^d - z^c == 7;
eq10 = x^c + 6 Sqrt[y] - Log[z^d] == 9;

Comment: I've added a way to replace the equations with those from the second set.

Comment: It is perfect!!! just what I expected.